# Is shadow dom a viable alternative yet to iframes for css encapsulation?

Tags: javascript, css, shadow-dom

I have a use case where I want to embed multiple independent web apps in a page. I'd like them to not be able to interfere with each others' CSS. Seems like a classic Shadow DOM use case. I am trying to determine whether Shadow DOM and the available polyfills (particularly ShadyDom and ShadyCSS) are sufficient to support my use case. Bear in mind that these are existing web apps. My main concern with the polyfills is that they seem like they might require me to make changes to the applications that aren't really feasible in terms of how styles are scoped and the DOM is addressed. Most of the examples out there are around building web components, but that's not really my use case. Is Shadow DOM (+ polyfills) a viable option for encapsulating CSS in all browsers today for existing web apps? Are there any examples of this out there?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is as long as it works with your use case ;-)